# Action of $\pi_1$ on homotopy classes of maps $[X,x_0;Y,y_0]$ vs. action of $\pi_1$ on the universal covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the following result in Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*, p.383. This is lemma 6 of section 7.3.

[image]

I believe I understand this proof. However, if I understand it correctly, it seems to me that all the vertical maps are not just isomorphisms, but are all the identity. Am I correct in saying this, or is there something I am missing. I worry that I am wrong as if they were the identity, why would he not just say so?

Comment: The verical maps need not be identities. Consider the covering transformation $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ (over $\mathbb{R}P^n$) given by the antipodal map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical maps are in general not identities which will be seen below.

Let me start with a preliminary remark. In my opinion it is not really expedient to consider pointed pairs when dealing with covering spaces. It only works when $\pi_1(B,y_0) \approx \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ which is a very serious restriction. Moreover, it seems to me that Spanier more precisely needs to require that the inclusion induced $\pi_1(B,y_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is an isomorphism. But that is another question. Anyway, I think we should restrict to $B = Y$ in which case we have (independent of $A$!)
$$\tilde B = \tilde Y ,$$
$$[X,A,x_0;Y,B,y_0] = [X,x_0;Y,y_0] , $$
$$[X,A,x_0; \tilde Y,\tilde B,\tilde y_0] = [X,x_0;\tilde Y, \tilde y_0] , $$ $$[X,A;\tilde Y, \tilde B] = [X,\tilde Y] . $$

This is what I shall do now , but of course you can also do it for pairs.

Spanier considers a covering transformation $g$ mapping $\tilde y_0$ to $\tilde y_1$ and a path $\tilde \omega$ from $\tilde y_0$ to $\tilde y_1$. From the general theory of covering spaces in Chapter 2 it is known that under Spanier's assumptions for any $\tilde y_1$ there is a *unique* covering transformation $g$ mapping $\tilde y_0$ to $\tilde y_1$. Similarly, since $\tilde Y$  is simply connected there is a *unique* homotopy class of paths $\tilde \omega$ from $\tilde y_0$ to $\tilde y_1$. Thus all we need to know is $\tilde y_1$; then $g$ and $[\tilde \omega]$ are uniquely determined by this point. Now $p_\#([\tilde \omega])$ is an element of $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ which is non-trivial unless $\tilde y_1 = \tilde y_0$.

Taking $(X,x_0) = (\tilde Y, \tilde y_0)$ we see that $g_\#$ is not the identity. Thus also the other maps are in general no identities.

Alternatively we can take $(X,x_0) = (S^1,*)$ in which case $[X,x_0;Y,y_0] = \pi_1(Y,y_0)$. With $a = p_\#([\tilde \omega])$ we see that $h_x : \pi_1(Y,y_0) \to \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is conjugation by $x$ which is in general not the identity (it is the identity, for example, if $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is abelian).